# Dynamic Paint - Second Canvas - crash on render

Tags: rendering, dynamic-paint

I have two emitter particle brushes.
I had one canvas (icosphere) and both brushes could paint on it.
I wanted a second icosphere that was identical to the first - and have both brushes able to paint on it - however, when I duplicated the sphere - It crashed on render.
When I deleted the second sphere - it rendered fine.
So I created a second sphere - from scratch - created a new canvas - tried to render - crash again.

I know I'm missing something - tried creating a separate material with vertex paint - tried changing paint map - no dice.  I know I'm missing something.

Ideas?

Comment: I've had some trobles with crashes in the past when using multiple simultaneous particle systems (not specifically with dynamic paint, but in almost every case). I partially solved it by baking the particle systems one at a time, i.e. create one system, bake it, create the next system, bake it and so on. This of course makes it difficult to make the particle systems interact in both directions, but the first system can still affect the following ones, the second one can still affect the third and later and so on. If that's acceptable, then try it out.

Comment: And... Don't set up any dynamic paint until after all particle systems have been baked.

Comment: I will try this - I didn't seem to have issue with the particle systems being brushes when there was only one canvas though - also I forgot to mention that the surfaces do not interact with the particles in any other way than dynamic paint - there is no collision or any other interaction.  I will report back after the bakes and next render attempt.

Comment: This might not be what's causing your problems, but it's what I thought of, since it was at least a little similar to my problems. Either way, you may have come across a bug.

Comment: What is the goal, each particle paint in a different color?

Comment: Didn't work, baked the particles and went back to bake, but interestingly enough it happened that I could bake when I had one dynamic paint canvas enabled - but not the second.

Comment: Ermod - the particle emitters do paint in two different colors. it is also necessary that they come from two different sources - but are both allowed to paint on both of the canvasses.  The addition of the second canvas is what's causing the crash.  It should be noted that these particle emitters are releasing 250,000 particles each.